# jQuery end() not working with extend()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have this custom jQuery function :

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    disable: function () {
        return $(this).each(function () {
            // function code
        });
    }
});
```

When I do something like this :

```
container.find('input')
    .disable()
    .end()
    .hide();
```

container is not hidden because after end I don't retrieve container.
If I replace disable by a core function like `prop()` or `css()`, then `end()` get container.

Is there a way to make extended functions behave like normal ones ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `$(this)` inside the `disable()` custom function, use `this`.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ox159gtL/1/)

```js
jQuery.fn.disable = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    console.log('disable');
  });
};

$('#container').find('input')
  .disable()
  .end()
  .css('background', 'yellow');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <input name="test" />
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can change the sequence of `hide()`, this way you don't need `end()`.

```
container
    .hide()
    .find('input')
    .disable();
```

Comment: This could do the trick but it means a lot of code change.
I would like something to make disable() return the same result than every jQuery function

Comment: What is strange is that disable seems to return the right stack, it's just not working with end().

Comment: As you can see, input should be replaced by "zzz". But it just stops

Comment: @Tushar: just in case you downvoted. my answer is updated before your edit. so technically i provided the solution first.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar That's not me, +1 for you

Comment: @Tushar: didnt meant to point you out but its annoying to get those downvote without any comments.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Yeah, I too hate that!

Answer (score 0):

You already have jquery object of element in context `this` in extend method. using `$` to convert is pointless. use `return this.each` instead of `return $(this).each(`

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    disable: function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            console.log('disable');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Read the question again, from the start, note the first snippet

Comment: Read the question again.